# R Making cumulative changes based on a conditon

Tags: r

Basically my situation is the following: I need to adjust the values in a column, but only if a condition is met and the adjustment needs to change every time it occurs.

I've been playing around with functions and loops, but I either get errors or not the result I wanted.

Consider the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(X = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want is only the values larger than 6 to be adjusted by +.5, BUT the adjustment needs to be cumulative, and preferably skipping the first occurrence. So the new one would look like this:

```
structure(list(X = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

So the forth row stays 6 since it's the first occurrence of a value larger than 5. The fifth row becomes 6.5 (6 + 1 x .5), the second occurrence is becomes 7 (6 + 2*.5), etc.

What I tried myself is the following, but I'm not sure it's the best approach here.

```
dummyfunction <- function(x){
  
  p <- length(x > 5)
  
  for (z in length(x)){
    
    if (x[z] < 5) {next}
    
    else {
      
      x  = x + .5*p
      
      p = p - 1
      
    } 
  }
  x
}) }}
```

Comment: `length(x > 5)` is incorrect: it’s the same as `length(x)`. I think you mean `sum(x > 5)`. `for (z in length(x))` is also incorrect — it will only iterate once; you probably meant `for (z in seq_along(x))` but you shouldn’t write that either: you just use `for  (z in x)`, and then use the value of `z` directly instead of subsetting `x[z]`. — Fundamentally, the entire loop could probably be replaced by a vectorised expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your problem description, I'm not quite sure I understand what you tried to do in your approach. Did you mean for `p` to start at `0` and have it then increment by `1` instead of decrementing it?

Here's a naive for-loop approach that might achieve what you're looking for.

```
dummyfunction <- function(x) {
  incr <- 0.0
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    if(x[i] >= 6) {
      x[i] <- x[i] + incr
      incr <- incr + 0.5
    }
  }
  x
}
```

And a vectorized approach with the help of [`cumsum()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cumsum).

```
dummyfunction <- function(x) {
  aboveSix <- x >= 6
  increments <- cumsum(aboveSix) * 0.5 - 0.5
  x[aboveSix] <- x[aboveSix] + increments[aboveSix]
  x
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really match the description, I know. What I tried to do get the maximum number of +.5 steps, and decrease the number of steps with each application, since the size of the increment doesn't really matter for the element it is applied to. As long as when it's above 5 its gets a increment and that increment is different (larger) from the other values above 5. But your suggestion seems to work, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interesting problem but the example could be better. If I have understood it correctly, here is an updated example and expected output

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 10))
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 6, 7.5, 2, 3, 5, 11))
```

and here is a vectorized solution :

```
inc <- 0.5
inds <- as.integer(df$x > 5)
df$x + (inc * pmax(cumsum(inds) - 1, 0) * inds)
#[1]  1.0  6.0  7.5  2.0  3.0  5.0 11.0
```

where `inc` is the increment that we want to apply everytime the condition is met (`> 5`)

`inds` returns 1/0 value where 1 meaning the condition is TRUE and 0 meaning it is FALSE.

Finally, `cumsum` calculates the condition being TRUE cumulatively and -1 is added because you want to ignore the first condition match. However, this has a risk that cumulative count could go less than 0, so to avoid that we use `pmax`.